# Why does 1 not equal 1?

Tags: python, boolean

Given:

```py
print("The detail is", self.model.sibling(index.row(), 1, index).data())
detail = self.model.sibling(index.row(), 1, index).data()
print(" and detail is", detail, bool(detail == 1))
solid = bool(detail == 1)
print("Detail:", detail, "Solid", solid, "Detail", self.model.sibling(index.row(), 1, index).data())
```

what do I get:

```
The detail is 1
 and detail is 1 False
Detail: 1 Solid False Detail 1
```

so `detail` is `1` but it's not equal to `1`. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the type of `detail`? My  guess is that it's not actually an `int`.

Comment: print(type(detail)) and see if it says int

Comment: Try to print `type(detail)`

Comment: You need a [example] first.

Comment: (That having said,  it looks like PyQt (you didn't even say that in the question! A [example] would have `from PyQt5 import stuff`) so read the documentation to see what data() returns)

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible that your variable detail is actually a string, so the code in question would actually translate to:

```
"1" == 1
```

Try casting into an integer by writing the following:

```
solid = int(detail) == 1
```

Comment: since the OP hasn't produced a minimally reproducible example, this is all speculation.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Leena, you are quite right. It is PyQt model and when diagnosing a problem I got caught out by a foible of the print() method......

```
>>> a = '1'  
>>> a
'1'
>>> print(a)
1
>>>
```

look Ma, no quotes on the output string! Casting fixes it nicely.

Does this count as a "miminal reproducible example"? Or am I expected to post a few hundred lines of code and my database for a simple question that Leena saw straightaway?

And for the forum police, I know I should have posted this as a comment but I can't get the code shorthand to work.

Comment: Nobody asked you to post hundreds of lines of code. That's not minimal reproducible example. May be few can see the error without minimal reproducible example. Others may not. Do you want to restrict yourself to few people who can do that?